# Measurability of functions continuous on the right

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Let $f\colon (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous on the right, i.e. 
for any $a\in(0,1)$ one has $\lim_{x\to a+0}f(x)=f(a)$.

> Is it true that $f$ is measurable?

I apologize if this question is too elementary for this site.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177917/are-right-continuous-functions-measurable